# Correct way to use custom functor with std::generate_n() algorithm?

Tags: c++, stl, functional-programming

The following code compiles correctly under VC++ 8 on XPSP3, but running it causes a runtime error.

My header looks like:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>


template<typename T>
class test_generator
{
    public:
    typedef T result_type;

    //constructor
    test_generator()
    {
        std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( tests ), 100, rand );
        value = tests.begin();
    }

    result_type operator()( void )
    {
        if( value == tests.end() )
        {
            throw std::logic_error( "" );
        }

            return *value++;
    }

    private:

    std::list<T> tests;
    typename std::list<T>::iterator value;

};
```

My implementation looks like:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    test_generator<double> test;
    std::deque<double> tests;

    std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( tests ), 10, test );

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine, it generates an exception (not the logic_error exception defined in the header).

If I change the implementation to use a function instead of a functor, it works:

```
int main()
{
    std::deque<int> tests;
    std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( tests ), 10, rand );

    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong with using a functor here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `test_generator` constructor initialises the `value` iterator to reference the first element in the `tests` list (which is a member of `test_generator`).

When you call `std::generate_n`, a copy of the `test` is made (because the object is passed by value). In the copied object, the `value` iterator refers to the `tests` list in the original object, not the copy.

Because of the iterator debugging checks performed in the Visual Studio STL implementation, this triggers an assertion, because an iterator obtained from one container should not be compared against an iterator from another container.

To fix the problem, you could either implement a copy constructor for your `test_generator` class, or defer initialisation of `value` until the first time `operator()` is invoked.

Comment: Moved the initialization of value into the initialization list, and implemented a copy constructor, this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out what's causing the exception so far, but you may wish to have `return *value++` in your `operator()`. :-)

Comment: changing *(value++) to *value++ had no affect.

Comment: I'm not saying that *value++ is different from *(value++), just that your sample code above lacked it. But it's good that your actual code (which you should paste, by the way) has it. :-)

Comment: sry about that... this is actually my real code... I just didn't catch that until after I posted.